# Hair Paricle System not rendering properly on plane

Tags: modifiers, particles

My scene involves a plane that has several modifiers:

- Subdivide, set to six.
- Array, set to -1 Y axis
- Array, set to +1 X axis
- Displace with a basic cloud texture

I tried following Andrew Price's tutorial on realistic grass, by adding the default hair particle system to the plane and setting the render to a group of grass, but the grass only appears in a small space in the render. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your .blend file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the *use modifier stack* checkbox is checked in the *Emission* section of Particle settings.

[image: Particle settings]

Comment: Remember to always cut out unnecessary parts of images.