# (Placement of hair)Hair particles ignores Weight Paint and Vertex Groups

Tags: particles

I'm trying to add hair to my model in Blender, but when I try to make the hair emit from only one place by using the tools in "Object Data: Vertex Groups" or by using Weight Paint, the hair doesn't move to where I painted, but stays in the same place. I tried using both version 2.67 and 2.72. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the Particle System such that the Vertex Groups affect the density of hairs. On the particle system tab, scroll down to the subsection Vertex Groups and add your group to the density.

Answer (score 4):

Assign the selected vertex group and name it.
[image]

Go to the *'Particles Menu'* header and input the vertex group name in the *Density* window (located in 'Vertex Grops' panel).
[image]

Edited:

I've checked your model and found the solution. In your case you have to **place the *'Particle system'* modifiers over the *'Mirror'* modifier**. As you can see below, the beard and tail particles are now assigned to the right vertex groups.
[image]

I can advise you few more things. Before adding the hair particles to your model, make sure that:

- it has a good topology
- the double vertices are removed (in 'Edit Mode' press <kbd>W</kbd>--> Remove Doubles)
- the normals are facing the right side (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in 'Edit Mode')
- the location, rotation and scale is applied (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in 'Object Mode')
- there are no ngons, non manifold elements, interior faces (you can check it very fast using a *'Mesh Lint'* addon)
- the 'Mirror Modifier is applied

Comment: Thankyou for answering! I have already done that though, and that doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmmm...That's strange. You may post your .blend file via http://pasteall.org/ if you like, so we can see what's the problem and find a solution.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33133

Comment: (Trying to add a tail and some light "beard")

Comment: I analized your model and I think it need a little "clean up" :). Your mesh need to be clean before applying the hair. Please see an answer in this thread:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/problems-with-particle-hair-in-2-72-cycles
I'll try to fix your mesh asap, so you may apply the hair properly soon.

Comment: I wouldn't apply the modifiers, just make sure the *use modifier stack* checkbox in the particle settings is checked and you should be able to put the particle systems last in the mod stack.  See [hair particle system not rendering properly on plane](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/hair-paricle-system-not-rendering-properly-on-plane/15404#15404).

Comment: Thankyou very much to both of you! Checking the "use modifier stack" did it :)